# Access jboss 8080 port inside docker container

Tags: bash, jboss, docker

I'm running jboss5 in centos6.7 docker contrainer.

JBoss running using `run.sh -b 0.0.0.0` command
Container running using `docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 my/jboss /bin/bash`

This is what I see in container

```
[root@e44f2bbab31a bin]# netstat -alnt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

This is what I see on host

```
15:04:17:(~)$ sudo docker ps
[sudo] password for c0rp: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e44f2bbab31a        my/jboss          "/bin/bash"         4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   thirsty_franklin
```

When I'm trying to access jboss application from host by `localhost:8080` I see `ERROR 404: Not Found.`

When I'm checking localhost:8080 from inside container using `wget` I see same error `ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Everything is ok if I'm using ip address of container. Question is how can I bind host localhost:8080 to container ip_address:8080 ?

Comment: Have you managed to access?

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is a alias for `127.0.0.1`. This address used for loopback. It means what your request will returned to the same machine on Network OSI model layer(through `lo0` interface in `ifconfig` command). But you can get access to your container using request to `localhost`:

1. !!!Very-very dirty hack!!! Don't use it. Just for understanding of localhost issue. You can edit hosts file (example for Mac):

   `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts`

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
   ::1             localhost
   ```

   Just replace `127.0.0.1` by ip of your container. I'm repeating: it's just for understanding of `localhost`
2. You can run `NGINX` instance on your `localhost` machine. You can configure it for sending all requests from `localhost:8080` to  `containerIp:8080` (best variant without any configuration with routing)

Answer (score 0):

I found that running

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap71-openshift
```

that I also needed to open the management port, so you (or rather, someone in the future coming across this thread) should try this:

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 [image name]
```